# How to add a div inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to show a custom alert in html using jquery. How can i fix this so it works?

This is where i declare the div in HTML

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls" id ="Alrt">

    </div> 
</div>
```

and this is where i try run it inside a jquery function

```
  $("#Alrt").val('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Loaded In</div>  ');
```

Comment: Use `.append` to d othis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is applicable only for input elements.

So in order to accomplish your task you have to use `.html()`

Try,

```
$("#Alrt").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Loaded In</div>');
```

Instead of,

```
$("#Alrt").val('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Loaded In</div>');
```

Comment: Thank You. that worked perfectly, and thanks for the explination

Answer (score 2):

Use `.html()` instead of `.val()`;

```
 $("#Alrt").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Loaded In</div>  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .html() for make it working.
I think this is what you need-
HTML-

```
<div class="control-group" id ="OuterDiv">
</div>
```

JS-

```
$("#OuterDiv").append('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>Loaded In</div>  ');
```

jsfiddle-
http://jsfiddle.net/zJy3d/1/